how to prevent playing more than one audio at the same time using expo
iam having a problem in my app that i can play more than one audio at the same time and i want to prevent this behavior to only play one audio at time
here is my compponent that play the audio
const Box = ({ item, data }) => {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(); // State to hold the sound object
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
//  =================== playing audio ===================
  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  const playTrack = async () => {
    if (sound) {
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    }

    if (!item?.audio) {
      return;
    }

    const { sound: newSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({
      uri: item.audio,
    });

    setSound(newSound);
    newSound.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
    await newSound.playAsync();
  };

  const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = (status) => {
    if (!status.isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    setIsPlaying(status.isPlaying);
  };

  const onPlayPause = async () => {
    if (!sound) {
      await playTrack();
    } else if (isPlaying) {
      await sound.pauseAsync();
    } else {
      await sound.playAsync();
    }
  };
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
<TouchableOpacity>
            <Ionicons
              onPress={onPlayPause}
              disabled={!item.audio}
              name={isPlaying ? "pause-outline" : "play-outline"}
              size={24}
              color={item.audio ? "#6961F8" : "gray"}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Box;

and this is its parent componenet i have tried to make state to track the audio from the parent but it didnt work
const TafseerDetails = ({ route }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="dark" />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.iconContainer}
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Image
          style={styles.icon}
          source={require("../assets/icons/arrow-left.png")}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Card data={data} />

      <Verses ayats={ayats} data={data} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default TafseerDetails;

const Verses = ({ ayats, data }) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlashList
        estimatedItemSize={200}
        data={ayats}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.number.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Box item={item} data={data}/>}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 450 }}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
          <View
            style={{
              height: 1,
              backgroundColor: "#f1f1f6",
              marginVertical: 20,
              marginHorizontal: 20,
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default Verses;


